# SQL Server - Nested child element in XML clause

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I use the below query in order to generate an XML output and later, an XML file into a location through a stored procedure. I have created a view as a middle layer between the stored procedure and the database (View -[DocProcess_Invoice]).

**Query**

```
SELECT TOP 1
IDInvoice AS ID,
'FALSE' AS CopyIndicator,
CAST(InvoiceIssueDate AS date) AS IssueDate,
'380' AS InvoiceTypeCode,
DocumentCurrencyCode,
'RON' AS TaxCurrencyCode,
'RON' AS PricingCurrencyCode,
'RON' AS PaymentCurrencyCode,
'RON' AS PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode,
LineCountNumeric,(
    SELECT 
        (SELECT
            IDOrderReference AS ID,
            IssueDate

            FROM RO_ErpZero.dbo.[DocProcess_Invoice] WHERE GID='1D70DC20-7E7D-4D08-AE3F-1E9466CB7508'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)

    FROM RO_ErpZero.dbo.[DocProcess_Invoice] 
    FOR XML PATH('OrderReference'), TYPE)

FROM RO_ErpZero.dbo.[DocProcess_Invoice] WHERE GID='1D70DC20-7E7D-4D08-AE3F-1E9466CB7508'
FOR XML PATH('Invoice'))
```

**Output**

```
<Invoice>
<ID>FAV-FDIS180-02436</ID>
<CopyIndicator>FALSE</CopyIndicator>
<IssueDate>2018-02-16</IssueDate>
<InvoiceTypeCode>380</InvoiceTypeCode>
<DocumentCurrencyCode>LEU</DocumentCurrencyCode>
<TaxCurrencyCode>RON</TaxCurrencyCode>
<PricingCurrencyCode>RON</PricingCurrencyCode>
<PaymentCurrencyCode>RON</PaymentCurrencyCode>
<PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode>RON</PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode>
<LineCountNumeric>1</LineCountNumeric>
<OrderReference>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
</OrderReference>
<OrderReference>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
</OrderReference>
<OrderReference>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
</OrderReference>
<OrderReference>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
</OrderReference>
</Invoice>
```

The purpose of the view is to return the invoice number and the lines on the invoice. The query result of the view is 4 rows and I believe, that since are four rows this is the reason that in the XML output I have forth times the tag `<ID>` and `<IssueDate>`.

**View result**

[image: Preview here]

The desired output I'm looking for should bring just once the `<ID>` and `<IssueDate>` within the `<OrderReference>` tag since it's the same order reference number for my invoice and for certain I'm missing something but I do not know what.

**Desired output**

```
<Invoice>
<ID>FAV-FDIS180-02436</ID>
<CopyIndicator>FALSE</CopyIndicator>
<IssueDate>2018-02-16</IssueDate>
<InvoiceTypeCode>380</InvoiceTypeCode>
<DocumentCurrencyCode>LEU</DocumentCurrencyCode>
<TaxCurrencyCode>RON</TaxCurrencyCode>
<PricingCurrencyCode>RON</PricingCurrencyCode>
<PaymentCurrencyCode>RON</PaymentCurrencyCode>
<PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode>RON</PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode>
<LineCountNumeric>1</LineCountNumeric>
<OrderReference>
<ID>0</ID>
<IssueDate>1900-01-01</IssueDate>
</OrderReference>
</Invoice>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are there many rows and why do you need just one? Is there any chance that these values are not the same and you'd need more of them within your XML?

If not, it might be enough to use `TOP 1` or `DISTINCT` in your sub-select

```
(SELECT TOP 1 --or DISTINCT
        IDOrderReference AS ID,
        IssueDate

        FROM RO_ErpZero.dbo.[DocProcess_Invoice] WHERE GID='1D70DC20-7E7D-4D08-AE3F-1E9466CB7508'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
```

This will reduce the result set to the first line (or to a distinct set).